# I am trying to send result of a query in xlsx format using SQL mail but in excel its not getting properly disturbed between columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to send result of a query in xlsx format using SQL mail but in excel its not
getting properly disturbed between columns and rows. I tried using below code.Its sending
excel attachment but not in proper format.

```
declare @table_name nvarchar(255)
declare @qry nvarchar(max)
declare @subject nvarchar(max)
declare @body nvarchar(max)



set @table_name='tmp.temp_table'

select @qry='select * from database_name.' + @table_name



EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                                   @profile_name = 'XYZ'
                                  ,@recipients = 'XYZ'
                                  ,@query_result_header = 1
                                  ,@query=@qry
                                  ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
                                  ,@query_no_truncate=1
                                  ,@query_attachment_filename = 'result.xlsx'
                                  ,@subject = @subject
                                  ,@body = @body
                                  ,@body_format ='HTML'
                                  ,@importance ='HIGH'
```

Could you please help me in bringing this to proper format.I tried using above code.Its sending
excel attachment but not in proper format.

Comment: why you think that proc makes your query result a proper excel format file?

Comment: You are generating an HTML file, not Excel. Using a fake `xlsx` extension won't fool Excel. It will open your file as HTML and *import the table data*.

Comment: Can you help me in resolving this issue.I thought that @query_attachment_filename = 'result.xlsx' will take care of this

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any method to send Excel files. And `sp_send_dbmail` is mainly for sending administration messages. Generating nicely formatted reports and emailing them is the job of Reporting Services